# How to calculate mean in a particular subset and replace the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, numpy-ndarray

csv table :

[image: csv table]

So I have a csv file that has different columns like nodeVolt, Temperature1, temperature2, temperature3, pressure and luminosity. Under temperatures column, there are various cells where the value is wrong (ie. 220). I want to replace that value in that cell by taking a mean of the previous 10 cells and replacing it there. I want this to run dynamically by finding all the cells with values 220 in that particular column and replace with the mean of previous 10 values in the same column.

I was able to search the cells containing 220 in that particular problem but unable to take mean and replace it.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

data = pd.read_csv(r"108e.csv")
data = data.drop(['timeStamp','nodeRSSI','packetID', 'solarPanelVolt', 'solarPanelBattVolt',  
                  'solarPanelCurr','temperature2','nodeVolt','nodeAddress'], axis = 1) 

df =  pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df.loc[lambda df: df['temperature3'] == 220]

print(df1)

for i in df1:
    df1["temperature3"][i] == df["temperature3"][i-11:i-1, 'temperature3'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "something": 3.37,
        "temperature3": [
            31.94,
            31.93,
            31.85,
            31.91,
            31.92,
            31.89,
            31.9,
            31.94,
            32.06,
            32.16,
            32.3,
            220,
            32.1,
            32.5,
            32.2,
            32.3,
        ],
    }
)

# replace all 220 values by NaN
df["temperature3"] = df["temperature3"].replace({220: np.nan})

# fill all NaNs with an shifted rolling average of the last 10 rows
df["temperature3"] = df["temperature3"].fillna(
    df["temperature3"].rolling(10, min_periods=1).mean().shift(1)
)
```

Result:

```
    something   temperature3
0   3.37    31.940
1   3.37    31.930
2   3.37    31.850
3   3.37    31.910
4   3.37    31.920
5   3.37    31.890
6   3.37    31.900
7   3.37    31.940
8   3.37    32.060
9   3.37    32.160
10  3.37    32.300
11  3.37    31.986
12  3.37    32.100
13  3.37    32.500
14  3.37    32.200
15  3.37    32.300
```

(please provide next time some sample data as code, not as an image)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have data of around 300000 rows. Once I implemented this I was able to change around 6000 rows of value and above that, it displays nan. What should I do to change the values of the whole csv file?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why just the sheer amount of the data would let this method fail, there is no limitation to apply this method on a larger data set. There must be some other issue with the data.

Comment: Maybe the data has a lot of consecutive NaN/220-values? The gap filling only works if there is at least non-NaN value in each rolling 10-value range.

Comment: But the condition is given in such a way that the rolling should only be done when it finds a nan value in the column right? However, Thank you so much for your answer. I was able to replace the 220 values with the mean using for loop and it works well.

Comment: Yes indeed, the min_periods=1 parameter indicates that at least one value must be available. However, happy that my answer was helpful. Also, please consider to mark the answer as an accepted answer.